# Avoiding importing packages when developing an R package

Tags: r, build, package

Suppose I am developing an R package in which I use just one function (say, Function "F") from Package "P".
I would use an **output of Function "F"** to do something else **within** my function.

To do so, I would include Package "P" in the "Imports:" section of the description.

Because "P" is a package to be imported, when someone installs my package, she would end up installing Package "P" as well, just because I use **one** of its functions, Function "F", inside some function in my package.

My questions are as follows:

1. How can I avoid forcing the user to install the entire Package "P"?
2. That is, can I get the user to install only Function "F" from Package "P"?
3. Can I just copy and paste the source code of "F" function into my package so that the user would not have to install the whole Package "P"?
4. Would the answer to Question 3 depend on which license Package "P" is under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are answers to your questions

1. By making your function unavailable or dysfunctional if that package isn't available. Your function would have to check if package P is available, and if not, throw an error or a warning and return. This means the user can decide to install package P to get the functionality of your package.
2. No way
3. Perhaps, see 4. In reality *it depends*.
4. Yes.

Answer 1 would be the easy recomendation for me to give, if the limitations (which are reduced functionality) is ok with you and your package.

Route 3 is the other viable option. It depends on a couple of things.

The license first and foremost.

Other than that, nothing really stops you.

BUT - I would spend some time trying to improve the situation.

Is Package P poorly designed? Is it bloated? I would contact the author and explain the problem. People getting together and talking solves all kinds of problems surprisingly easily. He or she is perhaps a nice person that welcomes interest in his or her work. Most people are.

Fragmenting the community code base (as you do if you rip stuff out of other packages), likely is not good as a whole.